# typo3: extension template namespace

Tags: templates, typo3

In the root template `page.10` is already taken. If I put `page.10` into my extension template, I override it. How can I **make sure** (just putting a large number is not "making sure") that I don't override anything? The root template is very complicated and includes many other templates, so I cannot really tell which numbers are already taken. I just want to use the extension template to append some content.

Answer (score 0):

The safest solution would be not adding anything automatically. Instead you could  provide your rendering instruction via `lib.*` or `tt_content.list.*` in case it is a registered plugin:

```
lib.yourContent = USER_INT
lib.yourContent { ... }
```

Then you only need to document how to add something to the page output, e.g.:

```
page.11 < lib.yourContent
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I use something like page.11 = USER_INT in my extension template. But page.11 is eventually already taken in the parent template. How do I prevent that clash?

Comment: I've updated my comment to make it clearer. You don't do anything with `page` at all in your extension template, you only provide the rendering object. It's up to the user/integrator of your extension to add this to `page`.

Comment: I still don't understand your answer, maybe I didn't describe the problem clearly: I am the admin of the page, there is no "user/integrator". Or I am the "user/integrator". I have a root remplate which I can see in the template module. On a subpage I want to create an extension template. In this extension template I need something like page.lastChild = mycontent. In your answer you're using page.11 and then you say "you don't do anything with page". That's confusing to me :/

Comment: If you have multiple templates then you need to add the last line I mentioned to each of them separately. This way you can make sure that you don't accidentally overwrite an existing index.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since you've asked this question.

You're saying "just putting a large number is not making sure" because you have no idea what content is using which number on the `page` object.

If you want to be 99,9% sure that a number has not been used, why don't you use the [current timestamp](http://www.currenttimestamp.com/) as a number on this [cObject](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#setup-page-1-2-3-4)? That's how the TYPO3 Errorhandler also refers to pages, using the timestamp they wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest answer if you can make sure which Page object index is already used for something is **you cannot**.
It might be set somewhere deeper in extensions, in any condition that meets any expression is defined there.
None of standard built in tools in TYPO3 can predict that and check all combinations of conditions to tell you if such number is set somewhere in some case.
But.

---

If you are an admin of that page, then the best approach is just to know your template.
Analyse the typoscript and know what numbers in Page object are used for something. Make a tidy consistent template, clean it up, check using Template tools -> Typoscript object browser. You have to know what's going on on your site, the elements in indexes of main Page object are the main and basis things which are shown public.
(Or just guess any random big number and try to search it in whole typoscript using Template tools -> Template Analyzer -> View complete TS listing. Let's be honest, probability that you shoot a big number which is already used is rather low)